# "unknown option: bash" passing a bash command in the "command:" section of docker-compose.yml

Tags: bash, docker-compose, keycloak

I'm using `quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest` to test a Keycloak feature. I'm using docker-compose.yml for this purpose

This is part of my docker-compose.yml file:

```
- KC_DB_PASSWORD=i5QRJNRmD13q8TEghc2v
            - KC_PROXY=edge
            - KC_HTTP_ENABLED=true
            - KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT=false
            - KEYCLOAK_IMPORT=/opt/keycloak/data/import
        command: >
            bash -c
            "
            /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build
            && /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh start --optimized --proxy edge --hostname-strict=false
            "
        depends_on:
            - database
```

But I get this error:

```
Unknown option: 'bash'
Did you mean: kc.sh show-config?
Try 'kc.sh --help' for more information on the available options.
```

What should I do?

Comment: The base image is?

Comment: @pierpy base image is `quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest`

Comment: No, I mean the "FROM" in the first line. Maybe you need to install bash

Comment: Not related to your immediate problem, but for `&&` to have the effect you want there either needs to be a line continuation after the word `build` or it needs to be moved back to the previous line. Because `/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build` is a complete command on its own, the shell assumes the default behavior identical to `;` when there's a newline after it instead of reading forward to see the `&&`.

Comment: (And beyond that, your command is already being parsed by a shell, so what's the point of `bash -c` at all?).

Comment: ...I _suspect_, but you aren't giving us enough information to conclusively diagnose, that `kc.sh` is your ENTRYPOINT -- so `bash` is being passed as an argument to `kc.sh` rather than being run as a command of its own.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

Did you mean to use `entrypoint` instead of `command`?

```yaml
entrypoint: >
  bash -c
  "
  /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build
  && /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh start --optimized --proxy edge --hostname-strict=false
  "
```

### Explanations

It seems like that entrypoint of your container is `kc.sh`, and you are appending a `bash [...]` command to it.

Basically, this is what gets executed:

```bash
kc.sh bash [...]
```

Because `bash` is not a valid subcommand of `kc.sh`, you get an error.

Comment: I'd argue that `kc.sh build` should be a RUN step anyhow, so the `command` should just be `start --optimized --proxy edge ...`, letting them use the entrypoint they already have. That way they only run a new build when the inputs change, instead of running a build even when the software being built is unmodified.